# I transformed data inputs and got the weights for my neural network model. How can I inverse the transformed weights to get original values?

Tags: scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def transpose(m):
    n = len(m[0])
    holder = []
    for i in range(n):
        current = []
        holder.append(current)
        
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(n):
        
            curr = m[i][j]
        
            holder[j].append(curr)
        
    return holder

data = [[61, 175, 111, 124, 130, 173, 169, 169, 160, 244, 257, 333, 199], 
 [13, 21, 24, 23, 64, 38, 33, 61, 39, 71, 112, 88, 54]]

y = [4, 18, 14, 18, 26, 26, 21, 30, 28, 36, 65, 62, 40]

data = transpose(data)

scalerX = StandardScaler()
scalerX.fit(data)
X = scalerX.transform(data)
X = X.reshape(len(X), 1, 2)

scalerY = StandardScaler()
y = np.array(y)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
scalerY.fit(y)
y = scalerY.transform(y)
y = y.reshape(13, 1, 1)

#I wrote my own Dense layer from scratch and called it FCLayer for 'fully connected'

fc = FCLayer(2, 1)  
net = Network()
net.add(fc)
net.use(mse, mse_prime)
net.fit(X, y, epochs=100, learning_rate=0.1)
print(fc.getWeights())
```

[image]

So essentiaally the weights represent the coefficient vector for my regression model but obviously the weights are scaled and so I was wondering how I can convert the scaled weight to what it would be originally.

I simply want to compare how the neural network performs against a linear regression model I made which is similar to the sklearn linear regression model.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by the scaling factors.

```
weights = fc.getWeights()
for idx, weight in weights:
   scaling_factor = scaler.scale_[idx]
   real_weight = weight/scaling_factor
   print (real_weight)
```